# Drawing bots is prohibited or not?

Tags: drawing

I'm pretty sure drawing animate objects is prohibited in Islam but can you explain about drawing robots, since robots only resemble human features but are actually inanimate, is drawing them prohibited too??

Comment: Well you could still have an issue with humanoid druids. Be aware that the question whether or not drawing is still prohibted is disputable the reason why the prophet pbuh prohibted such things are hardly given today at least for educated people.

Answer (score 1):

Asamulikum,
Humans make robots, so if we draw robots then it would be halal because we are not imitating the creation of Allah. Robots can also do good things. However, some robots are in the human form. So if you drew a robot, you could be drawing in a human form. So it could be haram.